# Two variable functions and continuity

Tags: question-verification

Since
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^4-y^4}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+y^2)=0$$

and
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^2\cdot\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}=0$$
because
$$\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq1$$
and
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^2=0$$
I may conclude that both functions
$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\displaystyle\frac{x^4-y^4}{x^4+y^4}, & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\ 0, &(x,y)=(0,0)\end{array}\right.$$
and
$$g(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\displaystyle\frac{x^4}{x^4+y^4}, & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\ 0, &(x,y)=(0,0)\end{array}\right.$$
are continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: Top line should have $-y^2$ at the end